# Jest coverage data not showing in report

Tags: node.js, jestjs, jest-junit

I'm trying to get test results and code coverage data after running jest tests. The resulting file contains the results of the tests, but no coverage data. I'm using jest-junit as my reporter. Here's what's in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose --silent --coverage --coverageDirectory=./",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "jest-junit"
    ],
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      "jest-junit"
    ]
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "outputDirectory": ".",
    "outputName": "junit.xml",
    "uniqueOutputName": "false",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " › ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  }
```